Enviar archivo de imagen y arreglos con Jquery con Formdata y C#
Estoy intentando enviar unos archivos de imágenes un arreglo y una lista con ajax pero al leerlo en el mantenedor no me pasa los valores de la lista, el valor es nulo.
El código que utilizo es:
                var ImagenSeleccionada1 = $("#fileProducto1")[0].files[0];
                var ImagenSeleccionada2 = $("#fileProducto2")[0].files[0];
                var ImagenSeleccionada3 = $("#fileProducto3")[0].files[0];
                var numero = $("#txtNumero").val();

                var transaccion = {
                    movUser : "@User.Identity.Name",
                    movIdTransaccion: "2",
                    movNumero: numero,
                    movEntidad: $("#cbbentidad").val()
                }

                var lista_conceptos = [];

                $("#tabla tbody tr").each(function (index) {
                    var concepto = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
                    var check = $(this).find("input").prop('checked');
                    var calificacion ="NO CUMPLE"
                    if (check) {
                        calificacion = "CUMPLE";
                    }
 lista_conceptos.push({
    movNumero: numero,  
    movIdTransaccion: 2,
    movConcepto: concepto,
    movCalificacion: calificacion,
     })
 })

console.log(lista_conceptos)

var request = new FormData();
request.append("objeto", JSON.stringify(transaccion));
request.append("listaconceptos", JSON.stringify(lista_conceptos));
request.append("archivoImagen1", ImagenSeleccionada1);
request.append("archivoImagen2", ImagenSeleccionada2);
request.append("archivoImagen3", ImagenSeleccionada3);

//ENVIAR TRANSACCIÓN
 jQuery.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("RegistrarInspeccion", "Transacciones")',
     type: "POST",
     data: request,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function (data) {
                     }
                 });


En el controlador el código que tengo para recibir los datos es el siguiente, he probado con varias opciones y la que mas se acerca es esta, la variable objeto me muestra el arreglo, pero la lista listaconceptos no contiene datos, el contador es cero. Antes del llamado a mantenedor, en el console.log se ven los datos de la lista, incluso en el parámetro enviado del request.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> RegistrarInspeccion(string objeto, List<EntidadDetalleTransaccion> listaconceptos, HttpPostedFileBase archivoImagen1, HttpPostedFileBase archivoImagen2, HttpPostedFileBase archivoImagen3)


Agradezco quien me pueda sugerir como solucionar.
